# Extract content from a cell based on search conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a column in google sheet in which each cell has a content like this:

```
The precursors of short story were legends, mythic tales, folk tales, fairy tales, fables 
and anecdotes which were present in various ancient communities across the world. These short pieces existed mostly in oral form and they were transmitted from one generation 
to another in oral form. **A large number** of such tales are found in ancient literature, from the Indian epics the Ramayana and the Mahabharata to the Homeric epics the Iliad and the 
**Odyssey**. The 1001 Arabian Nights, compiled for the first time probably in the 
eighth century, is also a storehouse of Middle Eastern folk tales and 
fairy tales. Emerging in the 17th century from oral storytelling traditions and above-mentioned written works of the ancient times (which themselves are based on oral traditions), 
the short story has grown to encompass a body of work so diverse as to defy easy characterization.
```

From this column I would like to extract only the content that is in between the **bolded** strings in a new cell. Which means, In this example, I want to extract:

```
**A large number** of such tales are found in ancient literature, from the Indian epics 
the Ramayana and the Mahabharata to the Homeric epics the Iliad and the **Odyssey**
```

Is this possible and do we have a formula for this? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's nice to have the ability to write custom function but in my opinion whenever possible one should leverage the build in functionality. In this case it's a simple regex.

```js
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?s)\*\*.+\*\*.+\*\*.+\*\*") // A1 is the cell with your target text
```

[image: image of working formula in google sheets]

Learn more about the regex by looking at this fiddle

https://regex101.com/r/yjp3Gc/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you included ***Excel*** in your tagging, I am giving and ***Excel*** solution.  Include the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function FrenchRoast(r As Range) As String
    Dim ch As String, i As Long
    Dim temp As String
    
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
        ch = Mid(r.Value, i, 1)
        If r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Or ch = " " Then
            temp = temp & ch
        End If
    Next i
    
    FrenchRoast = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
End Function
```

Then in the worksheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Google Sheet Custom Function

You can perform this operation using a **Google Sheet Custom Function** in Apps Script.

To create a custom function you will have to write a Google Apps Script function in the Google Sheet's Script Editor: From the top menu select `Tools>Script Editor`.

Here you can write a function that does what you want and you will be able to call it from the Spreadsheet as you call any other formula.

### Custom Formula Code

In this way you can leverage the JS String methods to search for the bold identifiers and slice the text accordingly.

```js
/**
* Always add this JS Doc parameter so that the formula name will pop up in the Spreadsheet autocomplete menu.
* @customfunction
*/
function GETBOLDTEXT(text) { // Text is the parameter you can pass through the Spreadsheet
  var start = text.indexOf("**");
  var end = text.lastIndexOf("**") + 2; // To append the ** at the end.
  return text.slice(start,end);
}
```

Given that the text you want to get is in the `A1` cell you can call it in your Spreadsheet like this:

```
=GETBOLDTEXT(A1)
```

### Refereces

[JS String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

[Apps Script Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)